# How can I yield a value from within a callback to a calling generator

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am trying to define something like the following generator in python 2.6:

```
def getGenerator(self, keyIterator):
    def bufferFullCallback(list_of_keys):
        some_values = api_call(list_of_keys)
        for value in some_values:
            yield value # I want this value to be yielded by getGenerator
    for key in keyIterator:
        with MyBuffer(self.buffer_size, bufferFullCallback) as buf:
            buf.addToBuffer(key)
```

In here, I get a callback when the buffer is full, wherein I make some API call to get a bunch of values corresponding to the keys. Now, I need 'getGenerator' to yield these values that it receives in the callback function. However, if I yield values in the callback, that callback essentially turns into a generator; this is clearly the wrong approach. Could you please suggest the correct way to yield values here from within a callback, or even perhaps a different refactoring that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def getGenerator(self, keyIterator):
    results = []
    def bufferFullCallback(list_of_keys):
        results.extend(api_call(list_of_keys))
    for key in keyIterator:
        with MyBuffer(self.buffer_size, bufferFullCallback) as buf:
            buf.addToBuffer(key)
            for value in results:
                yield value
```

Comment: This looks good prima facie and solves the stated issue. However, there is a related issue in that the callback gets called in the cleanup of MyBuffer (in its __exit__). I suppose that is expected and I should not be using the with block here?

Comment: Then just add one more loop to yield all results after the `with`.